# Create a link with independent text

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Is it possible to create an intra-document link with sphinx, such that the displayed text is independent of the link and destination?
Currently, I make intra-document links like so:

```
.. _Label_For_Section:

===============
Name Of Section
===============

The link :ref:`Label_For_Section` is rendered as "Name Of Section".
The link Label_For_Section_ is rendered as "Label_For_Section".
```

What I want is a way to have a link, where the destination text, link label, and displayed link text can all be different strings. Eg a link to a section called "A" with a label `.. _B:` which is rendered as "C"

### Note

I noticed that other kinds of links (eg external hyperlinks) are similarly constrained, and I figure the solutions may look similar, however I am looking specifically for a solution for intra-document links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Cross-referencing arbitrary locations](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#cross-referencing-arbitrary-locations), specifically the [`ref` role](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#role-ref).

```
:ref:`Link title <label-name>`
```